# Using dropdown selection with filter() function in excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, office365, dropdown

I stuck in excel sheet development.

I have table:

|  | 01.09.21 | 02.09.21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | x |  |
| Second |  | x |
| Third | x |  |

My formula: =FILTER(A:A;B:B = "x";"")

It works perfectly, when formula is written manually, but i need to make automation using dropdown. Dropdown is set as list of dates. I made cell with VLOOKUP, which returns me column letter, so i tried to make =FILTER(A:A;G1:G1 = "x";""), but formula fails to work. My guess is, that Excel do not use cell content as text, but as formula. Is there way of using cell content as text?

Comment: You can type your FILTER-function in a certain cell (let's say `X1`). You can then reference the spill-range in your data-list (`X1#`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to nest `XLOOKUP` in there. For example:

[image]

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=FILTER(A:A,XLOOKUP(E1,B1:C1,B:C)="x","")
```